# How to create footer links in drupal 6

Tags: 6

I am doing a site in Drupal 6, and I need to create footer links which needs to be displayed in the footer.

How can I create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create secondary links in admin/menus/secondary links.

Once completed, go to blocks/list/, look for your secondary links, and place them in the footer block region.